# gdp per capita view all countries

Tags: web-apps, data-visualization, statistics

[image]

---

Looking for a (free) webapp identical/similar to that shown but can:

- show all countries,
- without any lag on a $30 chromebook

Decent amount of ads is alright; sign-up is not.

Extra points for:

- ability to showhide by groups/regions even if these groups are not customizable (eg checkbox to showhide all africa/arab/oil-countries/protestant/CIS/latin/pop>12m/ASEAN/EAEU/etc)
- show average of past x years (eg instead of `34,768.18` for france per above, `34,768.18 (27584.35/33797.16 avg of 3.5) (26,809.4/24,825 avg of 10) (25,056.68/24,226.88 avg of 17)`)

- show numbers in percentages too

Bonus:

- include places that are not countries
- include "assortment of stuff" (not just gdp per capita)

---

<sub>Note that just a plain old static image will not work even for the 1st-req since I can't (hover across the years to) easily see the 200+ numbers for each year.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Our world in data is a good source, you can select any number of countries here: https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/gdp-per-capita-maddison?tab=chart

Comment: Some problems. The numbers are not real but are adjusted for inflation. Also, this is **not GDP**  graph but PPP graph. ((( Separately, No option to include the latest half decade? And it's a tru pain to have to tab-spacebar 200 times after every page refresh. )))

Comment: True, there are true also GDP numbers without cost of living adjustment (search for US$ on this page: https://ourworldindata.org/economic-growth#all-charts ). (Depending on what you want to do, you can also download the raw data on the page.)